# How to convert xcode 8 storyboard to xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I've developed my project with Xcode 8 and I need to change the project to Xcode 9. But in Xcode 9 the navigation and other UI got collapsed. So is there any procedure to change?[image]

[image]

Comment: define _"got collapsed"_, please, because basically you don't need to do anything with the UI, it is supposed to be same in Xcode9 as it was an Xcode8.

Comment: Please check with the image attached above. Actually it works fine in xcode 8.

Comment: that is nothing to do with Xcode8-9, that is just how different iOS SDKs work and compile your project... if you could share the implementation that would give a better overview about the possible origin of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no change in design from xcode 8 > xcode 9 except one change for iPhone-X, for supporting layout of iphone x you need to enable **safe area** from right panel, if you will not enable **Safe Area** then black bar will show.

Comment: I have already enabled the safe area but still I am getting black bars.

Comment: Did you migrate your app from an earlier version of Xcode? If so then Xcode is now making an assumption about your screen size and you need a way of indicating the actual screen size at run time.

There are two ways:

a) There is a chance of LaunchScreen missing. Create a LaunchScreen.storyboard file and add it to your project.

b) If you don't use a launch screen.

Go to your Target's settings and choose General, then App Icons and Launch Images. Now set "Launch Screen File" to your "main.storyboard" (or another storyboard if appropriate)